# how to remove null values in a table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, null

I have a table (TestTable) as follows

```
PK  |  COL1  |  COL2  |  COL3  |  COL4  |  COL5
1   |  1     |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL
2   |  NULL  |  43    |  1.5   |  7.8   |  NULL
3   |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  1
4   |  1     |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL
5   |  NULL  |  48    |  10.5  |  17.8  |  NULL
6   |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  1
```

I would like a result as follows

```
PK  |  COL1  |  COL2  |  COL3  |  COL4  |  COL5
1   |  1     |  43    |  1.5   |  7.8   |  1
2   |  1     |  48    |  10.5  |  17.8  |  1
```

I have tried the following

```
Select 
[COL1],
[COL2],
[COL3],
[COL4],
 (select top 1 
[COL5]  from  TestTable
where [COL5] is not null and PK <= t1.pk
order by PK DESC) as [COL5]
FROM TestTable as t1 
Where 
[COL1] IS NOT NULL AND
[COL2] IS NOT NULL AND
[COL3] IS NOT NULL AND
[COL4] IS NOT NULL
```

The script works however I get empty result set. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you descript the logic please?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Look like 
[COL1] IS NOT NULL AND
[COL2] IS NOT NULL AND
[COL3] IS NOT NULL AND
[COL4] IS NOT NULL. 
Condition is return empty result set. 
Can u enplane your logic.

Comment: yes, what dbms is this for? and version please. Solution options often depend on these facts. ok, see it now thanks.

Comment: how to decide that when col1=1  than col2=43 and col3=1.5. is there specific logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a value in `col1` followed by a set of rows that should be combined into one row until the next value in `col1`.

If so, you can do this by assigning to each row a count -- the number of non-null values in `col1` on or before the row.  This can then be used for aggregation.

You don't mention the database, so I'll do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select row_number() over (order by max(pk)) as pk,
       max(col1) as col1,
       max(col2) as col2,
       max(col3) as col3,
       max(col4) as col4,
       max(col5) as col5
from (select t.*,
             (select count(t2.col1)
              from testtable t2
              where t2.pk <= t.pk
             ) as grpid
      from testtable t
     ) t
group by grpid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any rows in TestTable where

```
[COL1] IS NOT NULL AND
[COL2] IS NOT NULL AND
[COL3] IS NOT NULL AND
[COL4] IS NOT NULL
```